# Pandas : Filter Data from one dataframe column and update another df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one situation in pandas . I have a excel file having a column called `item` it has some text . I have another dataframe  having a column called `brand`. I wanted to add the brand name in front of item column if brand string exist in item column text.

Here is my excel file snapshot.

[image]

My brand dataframe looks as below.

```
brand_df =  pd.DataFrame({'brand':['spark','hadoop','hive']})
```

I wanted to check if `brand_df` brand exist in `item_df`  or not. If brand exist then it should come under `update_column` name in front of item as below. 
[image]

As per pandas doc what  understand is we should map to achieve this but my map function look like below.

```
 self.item_df['updated_column'] = self.item_df["item"].map(lambda x : 'spark' if 'spark' in x else 'hive' if 'hive' in x else 'hadoop' if 'hadoop' in x else '' )
```

In above command the problem is it would be very difficult to work when you have long list of brands.

Can anyone suggest me the best way to approach this problem.

**Text version of excel content**

```
item
hadoop is fast
hive is sql on hdfs
spark is superfast
spark is awesome
AWS is emr function
```

Comment: Please give copyable text instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use words boundaries with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first matched value:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in brand_df['item'])

#if dont need words boundaries
#pat = '|'.join(brand_df['item'])
item_df['updated_column'] = item_df['item'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
```

Or if need all matched values use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
item_df['updated_column'] = item_df['item'].str.findall(pat).str.join(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `pd.Series.str.findall` and `str.join`:

```
df['update_column'] = df['item'].str.findall('|'.join(brand_df['brand'])).str[0]
```